# Dictionary items are not being all stored as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is mapping one value to another value and it has multiple keys.

```
replace_dict={
    "key1":
        {"abc": "ABCDE", "XYZ": "WXYZ"},
    "key2":
        {"Alabama": "AL", "Alaska": "AK"}}
```

when I run the code

`print(replace_dict.items())`

the output is:

```
dict_items([('key1', {'abc': 'ABCDE', 'XYZ': 'WXYZ'}), ('key2', {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK'})])
{'abc': 'ABCDE', 'XYZ': 'WXYZ'}
{'abc': 'ABCDE', 'XYZ': 'WXYZ'}
```

I was expecting for it to look more like

```
dict_items([('key1', {'abc': 'ABCDE', 'XYZ': 'WXYZ'}), ('key2', {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK'})])
{'abc': 'ABCDE', 'XYZ': 'WXYZ'}
{'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK'}
```

How do I correctly format the dictionary so the output is as desired?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. That's not the actual output; the actual output is just the first line. Where are the last two lines coming from? You need to make a [mre]. For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: i didnt make up the output that is just what i am getting. this is as minimal as this question can get?

Comment: Then you might be running the wrong script. If I run `print(replace_dict.items())`, I only get the first line. "Minimal" is not the important part, "reproducible" is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following formatting by using for loop in `replace_dict.items()`

Here are the few formatting examples

**Example 1**

```
for key, value in replace_dict.items():
    print(key)
```

Output:

```
key1
key2
```

**Example 2**

```
for key, value in replace_dict.items():
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
{'abc': 'ABCDE', 'XYZ': 'WXYZ'}
{'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK'}
```

**Example 3**

```
for key, value in replace_dict.items():
    print(key, ' : ', value)
```

Output:

```
key1  :  {'abc': 'ABCDE', 'XYZ': 'WXYZ'}
key2  :  {'Alabama': 'AL', 'Alaska': 'AK'}
```

Comment: How are examples 1 and 3 relevant? It looks like OP only wants the output like example 2.

Comment: Just shared different formatted output so he can understand what is going on with the code. It's not about getting desired output only it's about understanding the flow also